# Get the final url and save it in sql

Tags: php, wordpress, url, curl, redirect

I want to get the final URL of each redirection and store it in a database table, I want to do this in a rotator link.

I've tried using curl but the URL doesn't change. Change probe using `$ _SERVER ['REQUEST_URI']` in curl but I only get the main URL and not the final

```
$redirection_url1= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


function get_redirect_final_host_url($redirection_url1){
    $ch = curl_init($redirection_url1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow redirects
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // set referer on redirect
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // get access ssl
        curl_exec($ch);
        $target = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);
    $redirection_url = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($target)['host']);
    return $redirection_url;}
```

how can i get this done i'm trying to do it in a wordpress plugin

This is the complete code stores the data of each visitor but I want to add the final url

```
function lcl_add_to_visit_log($camp)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $visit_time=date("Y-m-d H:m:s",time());
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $redirection_url1= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


    function get_redirect_final_host_url($redirection_url1){
        $ch = curl_init($redirection_url1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow redirects
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // set referer on redirect
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // get access ssl
            curl_exec($ch);
            $target = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        curl_close($ch);
        $redirection_url = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($target)['host']);
    return $redirection_url;
}

    $SQL="INSERT INTO ".LINK_CLOAKER_STAT_TABLE." (camp_id, visit_time, ip, url_actual) VALUES(".$camp['id'].", '".$visit_time."', '".$ip."','".$redirection_url."')"; 
    $wpdb->query($SQL);
}
```